# can't require my gem - cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler, gemset

I want to require my gem. I create gemset, сhoose it. After create two files
.ruby-version and .ruby-gemset, next i do bundle init in Gemfile i write

```
gem 'codebreaker', git: 'https://github.com/somerepo', branch: 'development'
```

After this, bundle install. When i require 'codebreaker' - i take

```
<internal:/home/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- codebreaker (LoadError)
from <internal:/home/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

But when i do bundle info codebreaker, i see all description, which i do in gemspec

Comment: I think something in your gem might be off. Do you have a `lib/codebreaker.rb` file in your gem?

Comment: Hello, sure i have!